# PayPal API does not support Items?

Tags: paypal

PayPal does not support API to read/update Items? -as in the Items being sold. I see API for Payments, Vaults, sale Transactions, Orders, ...
I also checked PayPal Here SDK, I could not find one. Please let me know if I am looking at the wrong place. Where do I find the API to read Items - such as name of Item, Item Id, Item Price ...

Please refer to this image, pulled from Paypal website-  [image]
How is the list of items managed -what you see on the right is the list of items/services offered by the merchant. What you see on the left is the Transaction? My question is given the list of Items (on the right), how was it managed?

So when the merchant enters the information at the POS hardware it just remains local on the system or maybe on the cloud and PayPal does not expose API to manage/Read/GET the List? (sorry for the rhetorical question - could not frame it any other easy way)

Comment: That looks like [PayPal Here](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/credit-card-reader-how-to)

Comment: I had previously browsed through  https://github.com/PayPal-Mobile/android-here-sdk-dist/blob/master/docs/DeveloperGuide_Android.pdf. There is no reference to reference to Item List. Item only exists in the context of an Invoice, as in "Add Items to the Invoice".

Comment: To my knowledge there is no API to manage those items.  It's all local to the app.

Comment: OK  - so the merchant has a native application that informs the PayPalHere SDK about the Item as the invoice is being prepared. What confused me was that this example picture at a bicycle merchant had the app with a title as "PayPal" - it made me believe it is a PayPal provided app / webpage / ...  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the details of the item(s) on an order that was paid with PayPal?

If I understand you correctly then the [GetTransactionDetails API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) would give you what you're after.  It returns an details for any items that were included on the original payment request.

Comment: Yes, details similar to "Payment Item Fields". Is this information available outside a transaction?  I am trying to get access to this information before transaction occurs. Without Items Management I wonder how will a merchant enter Item pricing information. I guess I am missing something big here.

Comment: That would be handled in whatever shopping cart system you are using.  PayPal doesn't have a way to manage items directory, however, you could use the PayPal Button Manager to create hosted buttons for individual items.  Have you looked into that?

Comment: thank you - please refer to the Question - I revised it. The Hosted Solution might be a way to do what I want - I need to look at it better.

Answer (score 2):

Why would it?

Paypal is only interested in taking payment for an item.  You can send through a reference and a description, but paypal doesnt care about your items, so it doesnt provide an API.

Comment: Without Items Management I wonder how will a merchant enter Item pricing information - another system for Pricing, also how about online store? I guess I am missing something big here!

Comment: @Abhi You're not missing something, you're assuming Paypal manages your store - which it does **not**. Paypal is a **payment** option. You send it some total you want paid. That total represents "something" - an item or set of items. Therefore _you_ have to manage your own pricing, calculations and such _before_ you send it for payment.

Comment: @EdSF - thank you - please refer to the Question - I revised it.